# Vertical Axis Values vs. Secondary Data Series Values

Tags: excel, charts

I have a simple "Stacked Line with Markers" Chart Type with three columns of data; Month, Preventable Incidents and Non-Preventable Incidents. The chart looks at six months of data and charts the Preventable and Non-Preventable incidents. I have the months along the horizontal axis (Column A: A2:A7) with the Number of Collisions on the Vertical Axis. The Preventable Incident values are in Column B: B2:B7 and the Non-Preventable Incident values are in Column C: C2:C7.

The Preventable values data points on the chart correspond correctly to the Vertical Axis labels, but the Non-Preventable data points are skewed higher and do not correspond correctly to the Vertical Axis labels. I would greatly appreciate some help in understanding why this is the case and is there a way to have both data series plot correctly to the values in the Vertical Axis labels.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to use the "Line with Markers" instead of "Stacked Line".  The Stacked Line will plot the sum of the series together so that you can see the additive effect of both.  This doesn't help if you want exact values for both series.

[image: example charts]